# Can we restrict users with unresolved number of question?

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

Many times I see some users asking lots of question without accepting answer for old questions. So why can't we have restriction for number of question for a user just like we have for flag(I think so).

If there is no answer then it won't be counted.

If answer doesn't satisfy & they can flag it something kind of unresolved & someone can review it before they go further asking more question.

It came in my mind so many times & that's why I wanted to ask experience persons & moderator here that why can't we have some system like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepting an answer isn't mandatory, and a few months ago, the accept rate was [removed from profiles and usercards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951) because users were pestering users about it.

I suggest just ignoring these users.

Answer (score 1):

I think that punishing users for the fact they get answers they cannot accept is not fair. I would love to get an acceptable answer to each and every of my question for sure and I don't see how it's my fault if I don't. If you want higher acceptance rates, take time and ask users what's wrong with answers they got and how did they fail to work for them, and then provide better solutions, or edit answers to clarify them if that's the problem.